# OpenStack POST request "X-Auth-Token"

Tags: java, json, token, openstack

I'm writing a java code and i'm doing Http request to Openstack, using the json response.

I use this command to request a token:

```
curl -v -s -X POST http://$OS_URL:5000/v3/auth/tokens -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"auth": {"identity": {"methods": ["password"],"password": {"user": {"name": "$USERNAME","domain": {"name": "$DEFAULT_NAME"},"password": "PASSWORD"}}}}}'
```

It returns me a json. Now, for example, i want to create an image, but i don't know how to use the token to authenticate me to glance service. 
If i use this:

```
curl -v -s -X POST http://$OS_URL:9292/v2/images -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth_token: $TOKEN_ID" -d '{"container_format": "bare", "disk_format": "qcow2", "name": "NEWIMAGE" }'
```

It returns me Authorization error.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, when you request a token without scoping to a project, you may end up with some issues. Not sure why exactly, so this is probably not an answer. 
As a workaround request a token using a project:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "identity": {
      "methods": ["password"],
      "password": {
        "user": {
          "name": "username",
          "domain": { "id": "domain id" },
          "password": "password"
        }
            }
        },
        "scope": {
            "project": {
                "id": "project id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```